# Xilinx Number of LUT Slices decrease on pipelining

Tags: pipeline, xilinx, xilinx-ise, spartan

I am using Xilinx, particularly the family Spartan6. I am trying pipelining. I have successfully impleted a 3-stage pipeline and a 4-stage pipeline. There is a trend that i noticed, that is the number of LUT slices decreased, the number of register slices increased, and the minimum clock period decreased. Now i understand why the clock period decreased, but i didn't understand **decrease in LUT slices** and **increase in register slices**. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Slices is not an exact measurement. You should considder LUTs and registers as a measurement, but not slices. A slice is a group of LUTs and registers. Each has an utilization ratio. So you can have many slices but with a poor utilization.

Answer (score -2):

Pretty much sure that you are doing some last minute work on your computer architecture report. This link should help you in explaining the reduction in LUT slices.
http://www.fpgarelated.com/showthread/comp.arch.fpga/55104-1.php